# How to reference only one page item in the inline field? Oracle Apex

Tags: css, oracle-apex, inline

I am trying to change the color of the one-page item, but all of my page items are changed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
.t-Form-label,
P1_E1_2_1_1 {
        color: red;
}
```

I am writing this in the Inline field:

[image]

Comment: Without the DOM to look at it is difficult to say but you could try removing the comma so you have `.t-Form-label P1_E1_2_1_1 { color: red; }` and it is looking for a `P1_E1_2_1_1` element that is a child of an element with the class `t-Form-label` or you could use `P1_E1_2_1_1.t-Form-label { color: red; }` and look for the `P1_E1_2_1_1` that has the class `t-Form-label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test done on Apex version 22.1. Created page item `P70_ITEM1` and `P70_ITEM2` with template label "optional" (not "optional - floating"). This looks like this:

[image]

Inspect the first item in the chrome developer tools:

[image]

Note that the label for page item `P70_ITEM1` has an id of `P70_ITEM1_LABEL`. That id can be used as css selector and set as "Inline" in the "CSS" section of "Page Attributes":

[image]

Save and run the page:

[image]